# reset the calculator input box for the next operation in js

Tags: javascript, html, input, calculator

its a calculator in html5 and js.
after any operation if i press any button number it will be added to the end of the answer, if the operation is (2+2) the answer will be (4) if i press (5) button to do another operation it will be add to the end of 4 (45)
how can i reset the input box if an operation is already done and another one is started?

this is my code

```
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<style type="text/css">

.border-style{
    border: hidden;
}

.input-style{
    width:100%;
    height:38px;
}

    </style>
    </head>

    <body>

<form name="calc">

    <table border=3 align="center" width="40%" style="border:solid" >

    <tr>
        <td colspan="5" height="40px" width="71%" class="border-style">
            <input id="input" type="text" name="Num" value="0"       style="width:98%; height:20px" />
        </td>
        <td align="center" width="14.2%" class="border-style">
            <input type="button" value="C"    onclick="deleteDigit(this.form.Num)" class="input-style"   />
        </td>
        <td align="center" width="14.2%" class="border-style">
            <input type="button" value="CE" onclick="document.calc.Num.value = ' ' "  class="input-style" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td  height="40px" width="14.2%" class="border-style">
            <input type="button" value="x^y" onclick="power(this.form)"      class="input-style" />
        </td>
        <td  height="40px" width="14.2%" class="border-style">
            <input type="button" value="Sin"   onclick="sin(this.form)"class="input-style" />
        </td>
        <td  height="40px" width="14.2%" class="border-style">
            <input type="button" value="7" onclick="document.calc.Num.value += '7'" class="input-style" />
        </td>
        <td  height="40px" width="14.2%" class="border-style">
            <input type="button" value="8" onclick="document.calc.Num.value += '8'" class="input-style" />
        </td>
        <td  height="40px" width="14.2%" class="border-style">
            <input type="button" value="9" onclick="document.calc.Num.value += '9'" class="input-style" />
        </td>
        <td  height="40px" width="14.2%" class="border-style">
            <input type="button" value="+/-"onclick="flipSign(this.form.Num)" class="input-style" />
        </td>
        <td  height="40px" width="14.2%" class="border-style">
            <input type="button" value="mod"onclick="document.calc.Num.value +='%'" class="input-style"/>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td  height="40px" width="14.2%" class="border-style">
            <input type="button" value="root" onclick="sqrt(this.form)" class="input-style"/>
        </td>
        <td  height="40px" width="14.2%" class="border-style">
            <input type="button" value="cos" onclick="cos(this.form)" class="input-style" />
        </td>
        <td  height="40px" width="14.2%" class="border-style">
            <input type="button" value="4" onclick="document.calc.Num.value +='4'" class="input-style" />
        </td>
        <td  height="40px" width="14.2%" class="border-style">
            <input type="button" value="5"onclick="document.calc.Num.value +='5'" class="input-style" />
        </td>
        <td  height="40px" width="14.2%" class="border-style">
            <input type="button" value="6"onclick="document.calc.Num.value +='6'" class="input-style" />
        </td>
        <td  height="40px" width="14.2%" class="border-style">
            <input type="button" value="+"onclick="document.calc.Num.value +='+'" class="input-style" />
        </td>
        <td  height="40px" width="14.2%" class="border-style">
            <input type="button" value="-"onclick="document.calc.Num.value +='-'" class="input-style" />
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td  height="40px" width="14.2%" class="border-style">
            <input type="button" value="n!"onclick="factorial(this.form)" class="input-style"/>
        </td>
        <td  height="40px" width="14.2%" class="border-style">
            <input type="button" value="tan"onclick="tan(this.form)" class="input-style" />
        </td>
        <td  height="40px" width="14.2%" class="border-style">
            <input type="button" value="1"onclick="document.calc.Num.value +='1'" class="input-style" />
        </td>
        <td  height="40px" width="14.2%" class="border-style">
            <input type="button" value="2"onclick="document.calc.Num.value +='2'" class="input-style" />
        </td>
        <td  height="40px" width="14.2%" class="border-style">
            <input type="button" value="3"onclick="document.calc.Num.value +='3'" class="input-style" />
        </td>
        <td  height="40px" width="14.2%" class="border-style">
            <input type="button" value="*"onclick="document.calc.Num.value +='*'" class="input-style" />
        </td>
        <td  height="40px" width="14.2%" class="border-style">
            <input type="button" value="/"onclick="document.calc.Num.value +='/'" class="input-style" />
        </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td  height="40px" width="14.2%" class="border-style">
            <input type="button" value="fib"onclick="fib(this.form)"  class="input-style" />
        </td>
        <td  height="40px" width="14.2%" class="border-style">
            <input type="button" value="log"onclick="lg(this.form)"  class="input-style" />
        </td>
        <td  height="40px" width="14.2%" class="border-style">
            <input type="button" value="0"onclick="document.calc.Num.value +='0'"  class="input-style" />
        </td>
        <td  height="40px" width="14.2%" class="border-style">
            <input type="button" value="." onclick="document.calc.Num.value +='.'"  class="input-style" />
        </td>
        <td  height="40px" width="14.2%" class="border-style">
            <input type="button" value="10^x" onclick="powerten(this.form)"  class="input-style" />
        </td>
        <td  height="40px" width="14.2%" class="border-style">
            <input type="button" value="Ans" onclick="SaveANS()"  class="input-style" />
        </td>
        <td  height="40px" width="14.2%" class="border-style">
            <input type="button" value="=" onclick="equal(this.form)"  class="input-style" />
        </td>
   </tr>

   </table>

   <script type="text/javascript" >

// saving Ans
var Ans=0;


// Delete last digit entered
function deleteDigit(Num) {
    Num.value = Num.value.substring(0, Num.value.length - 1)
} 


// Power Function
function power(n){ 
    if (n.Num.value != "" && n.Num.value != 0 ){
        var p=prompt("Enter the power:")
        n.Num.value = Math.pow(n.Num.value,p)
        Ans=n.Num.value;
    }
    else 
        alert("Enter a number first")   
}


// sin Function
function sin(n) {
    n.Num.value = Math.sin(n.Num.value);
    Ans=n.Num.value;
}


// Flips the sign of the value 
function flipSign(Num) {
    if(Num.value.substring(0, 1) == "-")
        Num.value = Num.value.substring(1, Num.value.length)
    else
        Num.value = "-" + Num.value
}


// Square root Function
function sqrt(n) {
    if (n.Num.value != "" && n.Num.value != 0 ){
        var p=prompt("Enter the root:")
        p=1/p;
        n.Num.value = Math.pow(n.Num.value,p)
        Ans=n.Num.value;
    }
    else 
        alert(" please input the nuber first  !!!")   
}



// cos Function
function cos(n) {
    n.Num.value = Math.cos(n.Num.value);
    Ans=n.Num.value;
}


// Factorial Function
function factorial(n){
    var var1, var2;
    var1=1;
    var2=1;
    var x=n.Num.value;

    do {
        var1=var1*var2;
        var2=1+var2;
    }while(var2<=x);

    n.Num.value =var1;
    Ans=var1; 
 }


// tan Function 
function tan(n) {
    n.Num.value = Math.tan(n.Num.value);
    Ans=n.Num.value;
}


// Fibonacci Function
function fib(n){   
    var var1=0;
    var var2=1;
    var result;
    var x= n.Num.value;
    for ( var i=1 ; i<x ; i++){ 
        result=var1+var2;
        var1=var2;
        var2=result;
    }
    n.Num.value =result;
    Ans=result;
}


// Log Function
function lg(form) {
    n.Num.value = Math.log(n.Num.value);
    Ans=n.Num.value;
}


// 10^powr Function
function powerten(n) {  
    var x=n.Num.value;
    n.Num.value = Math.pow(10,x)
    Ans=n.Num.value;
}


function equal(n){
    var var1=eval(document.getElementById("input").value);
    result = eval(var1) ;
    document.getElementById("input").value = result ;
    Ans=result;

}


function SaveANS(){
    document.getElementById("input").value =Ans;
}

    </script>

    </form>
    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They must press the equal sign button in order to get an answer, correct?

Have a flag (a boolean variable, perhaps on the global scope) that is set to true when the equal sign is pressed (or the form is "submitted" if you're using the submit event correctly). Then, on any subsequent button click, if that flag is true, clear the input box before executing the normal routine–taking care to set the flag back to false, of course.

You may also want to ensure that your HTML is valid (starting and ending html and body tags, html5 doctype, etc.)

Comment: then i should use a function for onclick numbers rather than (document.calc.Num.value +=)?

Comment: That would be easiest, yes.

Comment: i will try it soon and if its work i will mark your aswer :D and thanks a lot